# save push notification data after deleting iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I faced this scenario when I was testing push notifications on iOS.
when user register to receive remote notification. He add list of conditions when achieved the user should receive  a notification. I keep this list of conditions on sqlite file on device. If the user deleted the app, this list is gone.

What is the best approach to handle this:

- Keep the conditions list on server so if user re-installed the app he
  can get the last list using his device token and continue receiving
  notification from server.
- If user deleted the app and reinstalled it, he should not see the old
  notifications.

I would appreciate your help,
thanks in advance

Comment: do you have an idea how to know when the user reinstalled the app?

Comment: I can check when app starts if there is notification list on server or not.

Comment: what about when user uninstalled the app? do you need to check if there is notif on server everytime the app starts? much efficient if you dont need to check server everytime app starts, check only when the user Uninstalled the app and installed it again after. so how would you know when user uninstalled the app? :) im facing the same problem.

Comment: if you can store these values in a plist and back it up on iCloud account.

Comment: I created a file on document directory to keep the flag. when I read the list from server I set it to yes. when delete app and reinstall it this file does not exist so I read list from server again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Keep the conditions list on server so if user re-installed the app he can get the last list using his device token and continue receiving notification from server.***

This is a good choice.

***If user deleted the app and reinstalled it, he should not see the old notifications.***

Keep a flag in the default plist as NO. on first start check if the user has already read notifications in the server using device token. then set flag to YES. So when next time user re-installs the app, you can provide the latest notifications as the list of already read notifications are safe on your server.

Happy coding